# How to retrieve max(current_day-1) records?

Tags: mysql

2016-01-11 is the max date present in database .

and the other records exists in the database is on 2016-01-08

I am trying to retrive the 2016-01-08 record this way

```
SELECT  *  from historical_data where  current_day = (SELECT max(current_day-1)  from historical_data) order by open_val desc
```

But I am no results.

How to retrieve  2016-01-08 records ??

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/38d3a/1

Thank you for the help, but I have found issue in the query when using it for my Application

This is my updated fiddle , sqlfiddle.com/#!9/eaade/1 , when using LIMIT 1 I am getting it only for one symbol . , is it possible to get last record t for every symbol – Preethi Jain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a row per day you can use this simple query

```
SELECT * FROM historical_data ORDER BY current_day DESC LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1
```

[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/38d3a/18)

**UPDATE**

For the case when you have more than one row per day you need query somehow like `DENSE_RANK` in `SQL Server` or `Oracle`.

I can suggest two approaches:

1)

```
SELECT * 
FROM historical_data
WHERE FIND_IN_SET( current_day, (    
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT current_day ORDER BY current_day DESC ) 
FROM historical_data )
) = 2
```

[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ae4a5/2)

2)

```
SELECT `symbol_name`, `current_day`, `open_val`, `high_val`,
       `low_val`, `close_val`, `last_val`, `prevclose_val`
FROM
(
    SELECT d.*,
        (CASE WHEN @prev = current_day THEN @rank
         WHEN @prev := current_day THEN @rank := @rank + 1 END) as rank
    FROM historical_data d,
        (SELECT @rank := 0, @prev := null) tmp
    ORDER BY d.current_day DESC
) t
WHERE t.rank = 2
```

[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/eaade/12)

Comment: This is my updated fiddle , http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/eaade/1 , when using LIMIT 1 i am getting it only for one symbol . , is it possible to get last record t for every symbol

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT MAX( current_day ) FROM historical_data
WHERE current_day < ( SELECT MAX( current_day )
FROM historical_data )
```

And for all data in row:

```
SELECT * FROM historical_data 
WHERE current_day < ( SELECT MAX( current_day ) FROM historical_data ) 
ORDER BY current_day DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: I want to retrive all the data of the prevoius day so i tried this way SELECT *  FROM historical_data
WHERE current_day < ( SELECT MAX( current_day )
FROM historical_data ) , could you please tell me why its giving  incorrect results ??

Comment: Because you don't get max but every smaller than max.